# Circle not drawing perfectly round on screen

Tags: android, canvas, drawing

I need to draw several circles from smaller to larger radius on canvas because it need to be updated regularly. I tried with drawing a circle first but the circle is looks like more oval. I need perfect circle. Also how can I get height and width of that Linearlayout dynamically so that I can place the circle at center screen.

Code is given here...

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawCanvas);
        Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#CD5C5C"));
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(4);
        Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(480,800,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bm);
        canvas.drawCircle(240, 400, 100, paint);
        ll.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bm));
    }
```

I am testing on real device with Android version 3.1 (API 12). Pls help.

Answer (score 0):

The circle you are drawing with the bitmap by giving the unequal width and height..For drawing the circle you need to pass the width and height of the bitmap equally. So try by giving the bitmap width and height equally.
Change the below line

```
Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(480,800,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

to

```
Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(480,480,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

Comment: Thank you @Prasad for your answer, but still its not perfect circle. Giving same width and height improves that circle (rendered) but not perfect circle. It is bigger in width than height. I tried giving less width size but same result.